# Printer crashing when trying to print from Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, printing, printers

I had an issue when that when I printed from IE that the printer would crash, and need to be restarted. I could find nothing about it online, and eventually fixed it so I thought I'd put it here just in case someone ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my main CSS file was being included, and apparently was too large for IE to handle when in print mode. I excluded this file from print (set the media to screen) and this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem but a different solution: In my case it was the custom font family that caused the crash. Disabling the custom